# why the indent will be broken when opening in vim against opening in Typora for a same .md file?

Tags: vim, markdown, indentation

I am newer and learning writing notes in vim with .md format.

when opening in vim, it shows:

```
command1     comment1
command2     comment2
command3     comment3
```

The 'comment' is indent, with tabstop=4, it means lots of 'blankspace' is insert between 'command' and 'comment'.

When opening this .md file in Typora, the indent of 'comment' is broken.
I guess when .md file shows from HTML or PDF, the indent is also broken.

How can it keep indent when edit in vim and reivew in Typora/HTML/PDF for a .md (markdown) file?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.
Tab space will 'break' when open in a markdown editor because the tab will not expand to spaces.

You can try put it in a 'code block'.
That's usually how I do it.
Put the text within three consecutive backtick characters.

```
command1    comment1
command2    comment2
command3    comment3
```

I know some people like to use non-breaking space  
You can try as well.

command1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;comment1
command2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;comment2
command3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;comment3

Comment: yes, put them in a code block works very well, the comment keeps indent now.
BTW, what is a non-breaking space? I don't understand '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' ?

Comment: It is a space that shall prevent new line break. And in will preserve consecutive spaces in markdown. You can try to put several &nbsp; after each other. I.e &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; should become 4 space in the markdown.